# Azure B2C integration with AWS Cognito Federated Identities

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, oauth, openid, azure-ad-b2c

I am the process of integrating Azure B2C with AWS, namely setting up AWS Cognito with Azure B2C as a Federated Identity provider and using it for login purposes for a Mobile App.

For the most part, I believe I have configured everything correctly. This is what I have done so far

1. I have created a B2C Tenant and set up an "Application" in the tenant as well as a SignUpAndSignInPolicy. The Application has both the native and web clients enabled and also allowed implicit flow.
2. I have configured my Azure B2C Tenant as an Identity Provider in AWS and have created the necessary Roles for the IdP.
3. I have created an AWS Cognito Identity Pool and configured it to use the above IdP
4. I am using the MSAL library to authenticate with Azure B2C, specifically the `MSALPublicClientApplication.init(clientId, kAuthority)` method followed by `acquireToken`.
5. This presents an interactive login in the browser and returns a token to the app via a custom url. The token is valid and I've verified it with the [JWT tool](http://calebb.net).
6. I then setup an `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider` with the Cognito Identity Pool created in step 3 and a custom identityProviderManager which is a class where I have implemented the getToken and logins methods as per AWS documentation .
7. I then pass the token from step 5 to Cognito via the "return AWSTask(["providerName: "id_token"] statement inside the logins method.

After a ton of going back and forth, I have managed to get through most of the hurdles along the way, however I am now getting a token validation error from AWS, specifically:

> error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=8
>   "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Invalid
>   login token. Couldn't verify signed token.}

Googling that error really doesn't produce a ton of results, but from what I can make out, the sequence of events in the app is correct, however AWS is complaining about the validation of the token when it communicates with Azure.

There isn't a lot in AWS that can be configured the Identity Provider, such as secrets, scopes, or any of that, so I'm not really sure where to look.

I am hoping that to a seasoned OpenID pro, this error message means more than it means to me.

Some of the things I'm unsure about that may be relevant.
1. Azure B2C has a concept of "Keys" under an application which I am not currently using, because there is nowhere that I can specify a key of sorts in my implementation.
2. The `MSALPublicClientApplication.init` method returns an application instance that I then use to call `application.acquireToken(forScopes: kScopes)`. I have no idea what to put for the scopes value because from what I've read, I only need "openid" and "offline_access", but when I try to specify those, I get an error that they're already included by default and that I can specify them in my API call. However, I am not allowed to leave this field blank so at the moment I have the Azure B2C Application ID (in the form of a GUID) which I'm not sure is correct.

Thanks a ton for your help!

Comment: What algorithm is the token signed with?

Answer (score 0):

Your set up looks correct. Not sure about MSAL library but when testing directly from Azure B2C console, you get different tokens depending on whether you mentioned your signin policy (using 'p' parameter) in the authorize URl. The one without this parameter works but the one with it does not. Something to do with how OIDC Discovery works and how it is configured in AWS IAM console.